# why mongodb on ubuntu server automatically shutdowns everyday?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-server

i have installed mongoDB on ubuntu server and it works well with my node project.
But now it shutdowns automatically and i don't know why it stops

Comment: This probably belongs on another stack exchange site, such as Server Fault, Super User, or similar.

Comment: actually i did'nt get what you are pointing at.. can you explain please.

Comment: Stack overflow is the part of the stack exchange network that's for questions about programming. For questions about using hardware and softeware, use https://superuser.com/ instead. For questions about maintaining servers or professional IT stuff or whatever, use https://serverfault.com/ . There are other stack exchange sites, too. This post doesn't have an actual coding question in it, so it's not a good question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have solved the issue by running an SDK on the server named 'pm2'
which helped me to run the mongo db without stoping.